# Mapi session exceeds maximum count of type objtMessage

Tags: exchange-2007

one client (it's allways the same client) has often problems with mapi sessions killed by the exchange server.
The Application Eventlog on the exchange logs eventid 9646 with source MSExchangeIS:

> Die MAPI-Sitzung '/o=xx/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=xxxx' hat die maximal zulässige Anzahl von 250 Objekten vom Typ 'objtMessage' überschritten.

The client has no eventlogs logged about this error.

I looked for installed Outlook Add-Ins and found the default add-ins from microsoft, an adobe pdf add-in (which I deactivated because it's not needed) and an "Octopus" plugin from telekom.

Octopus is a CTI-application that connects to Outlook.
My guess is, that Octopus (or its add-in) causes this error because this client has over 1100 contacts.

My question is: how can I find out, which application/add-in causes this problem?

Edit: I already looked at eventid.net but nothing helped.

Edit2: Exchange-Cache-Mode is not used nor are there any shared folders / mailboxes open.

Comment: I have seen this before, when one of our user has a Google Desktop. His outlook 2007, will loose connection to Exchange and the MAPI connection exceeded error.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the add-ins one at a time until the errors ceased to be logged.

Comment: First, thanks for your answer joeqwerty.
Now there are only the default add-ins from microsoft and the octopus add-in. These are all used by every user. I would like to find the specific problem itself (not only to find out the failing add-in). For example, if the octopus add-in is the failing add-in, I would like to give that information to the developer to let them fix it. For that, I have to find out what action from which application / add-in fails.

Comment: The first step is to identify the add-in that's causing the problem by disabling them one at a time until the problem goes away. Then when you've identified it you can re-enaqble it and then invoke it's actions one at a time until you see the problem occur. If the Octopus add-in is reading, writing, or synchronizing Contacts or emails and the user has a large number of either, that would be my guess as to what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We found this was the symptom when users were 
- using Cached Exchange Mode
- had it configured to download public folder favourites
- had many public folders in their favourites

We found no fix for it, we just had to tell users not to add too many PFs to their favourites or turn off the cached mode

Answer (score 0):

Check out this technet blog [post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2008/11/25/how-to-get-rid-of-9646-events.aspx) by Jeff Stokes, on troubleshooting the issues.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, thanks for your link. There is described how to fix issues where to many sessions are opened. In my case, there are too many Objects of type objtMessage (not session).